# how do I write arrays to state?

Tags: javascript, arrays, state, push

I have a state of this type:

```js
this.state = {
        height: [],
        offset: [],
      };
```

I change it as follows:

```js
onLayout={({ nativeEvent: { layout } }) => {
            this.setState({ height: [layout.height], offset: [layout.y] });
          }}
```

how do I push them to another array in this form:

```js
[[this.state.height], [this.state.offset]]
```

I want each array to have multiple values, like this:

```js
[[234, 23423, 2323], [12312,21312]]
```

Comment: I dont think it's clear what you are trying to do, can you further specify the problem or what your goal is?

Comment: I want to have two arrays in one common array:
1) array with field heights
2) array with margins

Comment: I updated the question, please take a look

Comment: layout.height and layout.y returns array?

Comment: please specify type of layout thanks.

Comment: they return numbers
I want the heights and margins to be recorded each in a different array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your comment, you just have to set the state like this (if I understand it right?):

```
onLayout={({ nativeEvent: { layout } }) => {
            this.setState({ height: [[layout.height, value2, value3 ]], offset: [[layout.y, value2, value3]] });
          }}
```

Like this you get an array inside the state array, but I'm honestly not sure if that answers your question?

Having a single array inside a array does not sound that usefull to me.